# Replacing the corresponding column values in Python Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame, say :

> ```
>   Name  Visits
> 0 Z      0
> 1 A      0
> 2 B      1
> 3 C      1
> 4 D      0
> 5 E      0
> ```

Now, I made a list with those names whose visits are 0, so it has Z, A, D, and E. Now, I randomly choose 2 names from these 4. Then, I want to increase the visits of these 2 people by 1. How do I reference only these 2 names, access their corresponding visits and alter it? [In python, Pandas]
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a posible solution:

```py
df.visit[df.visit == 0] += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you already have list of who visited 0 times you can use [`pd.Series.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) to create a boolean mask for boolean indexing then increase corresponding values by 1

```
vals = ['Z', 'A', 'D', 'E']
m = df['Name'].isin(vals)
df.loc[m, 'Visits']+=1
# This only increases Z, A, D, E visits by 1
```

Comment: this worked for me, thanks a lot! I just replaced vals with the random list containing 2 names and it worked like a charm, thanks a lot!!

Comment: Glad to help. Take a look at BEN's answer much better than mine TBH ;)

Comment: is there a way I can contact you @Ch3esteR lol please don't say no?

Comment: @YamiKanashi Yes sure through StackOverflow chat.

Answer (score 1):

Try `random.choice` from number then assign value by `index`

```
df.loc[np.random.choice(df.index[df.Visits==0],2),'Visits'] += 1
df
Out[95]: 
  Name  Visits
0    Z       1
1    A       0
2    B       1
3    C       1
4    D       0
5    E       0
```

Comment: Edited answer as OP wanted to increase by 1. Feel free revert changes if not okay.